# VB error "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)"

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, snRow As Range, TmRow As Range
    Dim x As Integer, ETRow As Long, LTRow As Long
    Dim TMName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ETRow = 10: LTRow = 10
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AG5,C11:L41").ClearContents
    For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(x).Name <> "Summary" Then
        With Sheets(Sheets(x).Name)
            TMName = Left(Sheets(x).Name, 6)
            With .Range("C:C")
             Set snRow = .Find("Total Staff (inc Supervisors)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            End With
            Set rng = .Range("D5", "AH5")
            For Each r In rng
                If InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then
                    With Sheets("Summary")
                        .Cells(5, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                        With .Range("I9:L9")
                            Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                        End With
   .Cells(LTRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "LT", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                        LTRow = LTRow + 1
                    End With
                ElseIf InStr(1, r.Value, "ET") > 0 Then
                    With Sheets("Summary")
                        .Cells(4, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                        With .Range("C9:F9")
                            Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                        End With
                        .Cells(ETRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "ET", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                        ETRow = ETRow + 1
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

It is saying there is an issue with

```
.Cells(LTRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "LT", vbTextCompare) - 1)
```

and

```
.Cells(ETRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "ET", vbTextCompare) - 1)
```

This code works on a roster with 4 sheets if the user puts in ET or LT next to the date it then counts if someone is on duty (signified by W)

The code is for summary sheet.

Not sure why as it doesn't work but as soon as I try to change the actual summary sheet by adding an extra row below C5 this happens. Then even if I undo everything, it still occurs.

Comment: If `InStr(...)` = 0 then you have `Left(r.Value,-1)` >> error.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, sorry

Comment: @CallumDA - but `Left("test",-1)` would give runtime `5` and the OP is getting `91`. There is some other problem before this.

Comment: How does it say that it has problems with 2 lines? Usually the error stops on one line only.

Comment: Sorry it varies between the two one can be the LT line and another time it can be ET line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning value to 
`.Cells(LTRow, TmRow.Column)` and in the line before you have:

```
Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Thus, if `TmRow` is not assigned to a value through the `.Find()`, `TmRow.Column` would give this error.

Try to go around like this:

```
With .Range("I9:L9")
    Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If TmRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "TmRow knows nothing"
        Stop
    End If
End With
```

Then think of a way to rebuild your code.

Comment: Thank you Vityata,The code has been working just fine it is only when I add a row then it throws the error up.

Comment: @PhpNewbie - did you try adding the `msgbox()`?

Comment: Yes it seemed stopped any errors but it also stopped the program from functioning properly, instead of showing now many people were working on that day it would just show 0

Comment: @PhpNewbie - so the problem is that `.Find()` does not find anything and `TmRow` is `Nothing`?

Comment: it only seems to stop wokring and the error gets thrown up if I add a row below C6, but thank you for your help, I am sure if I rewrite the script then I can check for bugs as I go.